# IF ELSE condition in visualforce

Tags: visualforce

I have one picklist called "status". when the status is 'yes' in my visualforce page status column will appear & when it is 'No' the column won't show. But here in my code for 'Yes' status also the column is not appearing. Can anyone help me?

```
<apex:panelGroup rendered="{!status == 'Yes'}">
    <td width="20%" bgcolor="#D3D3D3" align="center">Name</td>
    <td width="10%" bgcolor="#D3D3D3" align="center">Status</td>
</apex:panelGroup>
<apex:panelGroup rendered="{!status != 'Yes'}">
    <td colspan="2" width="20%" bgcolor="#D3D3D3" align="center">Name</td>
</apex:panelGroup>
```

Comment: You can use a simple javascript function to do that or can use controller to have a boolean property and use that property in your vf page with `rendered` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting like <> instead of !=

means

```
<apex:panelGroup rendered="{!status <> 'Yes'}">
```

Hope this might helps....

Comment: but if i am replacing '=' with '<>' other columns are shifting outside

Comment: actually the problem is with = function. for != function  its working. & by replacing also nothing is changing

Comment: If the Status is YES, then you want to show the Name and Status
But if the Status is NO, then you want to show the Name only. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_panelGroup.htm) for `<apex:panelGroup`. This VF component must be a child component of an `<apex:panelGrid>`. If you read carefully you can see `<apex:panelGrid` generates a **HTML table** element and `<apex:panelGroup` combines two or more element inside a single **td** element as shown below.

VF page

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:panelGrid columns="3" id="theGrid">
        <apex:outputText value="First" id="theFirst"/>
        <apex:outputText value="Second" id="theSecond"/>
        <apex:panelGroup id="theGroup">
            <apex:outputText value="Third" id="theThird"/>
            <apex:outputText value="Fourth" id="theFourth"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
    </apex:panelGrid>
</apex:page>
```

HTML Rendered in browser As

```
<table id="theGrid">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span id="theFirst">First</span></td>
            <td><span id="theSecond">Second</span></td>
            <td><span id="theGroup">
                    <span id="theThird">Third</span>
                    <span id="theFourth">Fourth</span>
                </span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In your case you have written only `<td>` element directly inside the `<apex:panelGroup` and `<apex:panelGrid`. **This will break** the Salesforce generated table structure as there is a mix up of td elements generated by salesforce and written by you.

If you want to use td element you have to complete it with complete table structure as below. Then rendered attribute will work as a charm.

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
    <apex:panelGrid columns="2" border="0" width="100%">
        <apex:panelGroup>
            <apex:outputPanel >
                <table style="width:100%;" border="1">
                    <tr><td>...</td></tr>
                </table>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:outputPanel >
                <table style="width:100%;" border="1">
                    <tr><td>....</td></tr>
                </table>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:panelGroup>       
            <apex:outputPanel >
                <table style="width:100%;" border="1">
                    <tr><td>...</td></tr>
                </table>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:panelGroup>
    </apex:panelGrid>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please edit the second rendered block as follows

```
<apex:panelGroup rendered="{!NOT(status == 'Yes')}">
```

Hope this helps :)